# Sort dictionary based on len(value) where value is a set

Tags: dictionary, python-3.7

I know there are many solutions ([How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top])) to sorting a dictionary by values. However, most of those predate python 3.7's changes to dictionary.

I am also aware of [Fastest way to sort a python 3.7+ dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493838/fastest-way-to-sort-a-python-3-7-dictionary), which seems close to the answer I need.

I have a large dictionary of keys that are ints and values that are sets of strings.

I want to create a new dictionary that is sorted by the length of the set of each value.

Dictionary:

```py
dict1={
'12':{'sym1', 'sym2'},
'13':{'sym1', 'sym4', 'sym5', 'sym6'},
'14':{'sym1', 'sym3'},
'15':{'sym2'},
'16':{'sym2'},
'17':{'sym2'},
'18':{'sym3', 'sym89', 'sym34', 'sym5', 'sym88'}
}
```

New sorted dictionary:

```py
>>sorted_dict1

{
'18':{'sym3', 'sym89', 'sym34', 'sym5', 'sym88'},
'13':{'sym1', 'sym4', 'sym5', 'sym6'},
'12':{'sym1', 'sym2'},
'14':{'sym1', 'sym3'},
'15':{'sym2'},
'16':{'sym2'},
'17':{'sym2'}
}
```

Comment: `sorted()`  has a `key` parameter, that is used to specify the way items are sorted. You might be able to set it to sort by length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very slow way to do this, but here goes:

1. create a dictionary that has the same keys, and the value is the length of the set of the key

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dict1={
'12':{'sym1', 'sym2'},
'13':{'sym1', 'sym4', 'sym5', 'sym6'},
'14':{'sym1', 'sym3'},
'15':{'sym2'},
'16':{'sym2'},
'17':{'sym2'},
'18':{'sym3', 'sym89', 'sym34', 'sym5', 'sym88'}
}

dict1_len ={}
for k,v in dict1.items():
    dict1_len.update({k:len(v)})
```

2. Sort `dict1_len` by the value numbers in reverse (descending).

```py
sorted_dict1_len = {k: v for k,v in sorted(dict1_len.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)}
```

3. using the keys in the order given by `sorted_dict1_len`, add the key and the values of that key as given by the original `dict1` to `sorted_dict1`.

```py
sorted_dict1 = {}

for k in sorted_dict1_len.keys():
    print(k)
    sorted_dict1.update({k:dict1.get(k)})
```

#### Edit: improved answer

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dict1={
'12':{'sym1', 'sym2'},
'13':{'sym1', 'sym4', 'sym5', 'sym6'},
'14':{'sym1', 'sym3'},
'15':{'sym2'},
'16':{'sym2'},
'17':{'sym2'},
'18':{'sym3', 'sym89', 'sym34', 'sym5', 'sym88'}
}

def len_val(tup):
    return len(tup[1]) # length of the value i.e. elements in set

dict2 = sorted(dict1.items(), key=len_val, reverse=True)

print(dict2)
```

returns

```py
[('18', {'sym88', 'sym5', 'sym89', 'sym3', 'sym34'}), ('13', {'sym1', 'sym5', 'sym6', 'sym4'}), ('12', {'sym1', 'sym2'}), ('14', {'sym3', 'sym1'}), ('15', {'sym2'}), ('16', {'sym2'}), ('17', {'sym2'})]
```