# How to quickly sort dict by date

Tags: python, performance, python-3.7

The following code generates a dict and sort it by date.

I want to reduce processing time for this code. The processing time on my PC is about **0.27** seconds.

Is there any better way?

You can change the type of date data if you can speed up this code(The date type is converted to the string type in this code).

```
import time
import datetime
import random
# 0.27 sec
dic_date = {}
for i in range(0, 100000):
    year = int(random.ramdom()*1000)
    str_date = '{0:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime(year,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i))
    dic_date[i] = {"dummy1":i, "dummy2":i, "date":str_date}

start = time.time()

dic_sorted = sorted(dic_date.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]["date"], reverse=True)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start
print ("elapsed_time:{0}".format(elapsed_time) + "[sec]")
```

Comment: i  think you are looking for this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569360/3053228

Comment: Thank  you for the information.