# How to reorder an OrderedDict according to a list of values in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I am trying to find out how to reorder my OrderedDict with a list of values.
This is my code:

```
import collections

dicti = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dicti.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
desired_dict_order = [3,2,1]

print 'ordered_dict before reordering =', ordered_dict   

for key in desired_dict_order:
    ordered_dict[key] =  ordered_dict.popitem(key)

print 'ordered_dict after reordering =', ordered_dict
```

I got this idea from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925731/reorder-dictionary-in-python-according-to-a-list-of-values) <[please see it] which also answers this question, but I am doing this in Python 2.7 and it doesn’t seem to work, for the output yields this weird result which I do not understand:

```
ordered_dict before reordering = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
ordered_dict after reordering = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), (1, (2, (3, ('c', 3))))])
```

What is it doing and how can I achieve it in the right way?

EDIT: I would like to reorder based on the indices of the OrderedDict, so in the end I could reorder the dict even if the dict-keys as well as the dict-values are anything and don't nessecarily enumerate sequentially (like 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

```
ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dicti.items(), key=lambda t: t[1],reverse=True))
```

Will this produce what you want?
Because you are sorting already on the key, so why not directly sort on the value in reverse?

Comment: Yes in this case but I almost certainly know it’s not the functionality I want because it doens’t use the the ‘desired_dict_order’.

In the case of the thread I mentioned, the order list is '[5,2,4,3,1]’, so there you would certainly need it as I also want to be able in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
desired_dict_order = [3,2,1] # this is a list of numbers - values in your dict, not keys!

print 'ordered_dict before reordering =', ordered_dict   

for key in desired_dict_order: # …but here you're using them as keys, which is wrong
    ordered_dict[key] =  ordered_dict.popitem(key)
```

Easy way to do the reordering is:

```
aux_dict = { v: k for k, v in ordered_dict.items() } # reversed dict - keys and values swapped!
ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict( [ (aux_dict[v], v) for v in desired_dict_order ] )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and the code works, but I don’t understand why it is a problem that it is a list of numbers, as noone in the thread I mentioned calls that out as a problem and numbers are also used to indicate indices. Could you elaborate?

Also: the code you made is very confusing to me as a Python beginner, what exactly is happening there and what python ‘features’ or ‘functionality’ are used that I could study?

Thanks again.

Comment: Your dict has strings as keys and numbers as values. Your list `desired_dict_order` contains numbers - the values you want to order, right? - but there are **no such keys** in `ordered_dict`. That's why assigning to `ordered_dict[key]` created new entries that surprised you.

Comment: As for the features I used - read https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension and https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension

Comment: Oh so ordered_dict[number] doesn’t refer to indices like it is with lists (i.e. list[number])?

I actually do not need in the end to order based on the values 1,2,3.. they just happen to enumerate correctly in this simple example code i use to try things out..

I actually want to reorder based on index of the dictionary. How is that done? (I’ll add an edit to my post)

Comment: There is no such thing as "index of the dictionary". Dictionaries has keys, not indices.

Comment: So would that mean that with Python 2.7 u can not easily 'reorder the dict (like in the Python 3 thread) if the dict-keys as well as the dict-values are random and don't nessecarily enumerate sequentially’? Would you think it is still possible somehow?